# Is it possible to assess the contents of a capture group again?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, pcre

More out of curiosity than anything else (given the time I've spent on this), I'm trying to see if I can use the replace function in Sublime Text 3 with regex to convert

`style="bla: bla; bla:bla;"`

into

```
bla:bla;
bla:bla;
```

I'm able to create a capture for just `bla: bla; bla:bla;`, without `style` or the quotation marks:

`(?<=\sstyle=")(.*)(?=")` https://regex101.com/r/tctJti/1

After that though, I'm stuck. I've also tried capturing every `bla:bla` seperately, but that doesn't even seem to help, since the capture group then only holds the last thing it captured:

`\s*style="((.*?;)*)"` https://regex101.com/r/tctJti/2

What I would need is to be able to tell sublime to ignore everything outside that capture group from my first example, and then inside that single capture group look for semicolons, and transform those into newlines. Is something like that even possible, or is that by definition a two-step conversion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, try `\s*(?:\G(?!\A)\s*|style=")(?:([^;"]+;)|")` and replace with `$1\n`

Comment: Yup, that works just fine as well. Only thing is that it always removes any whitespace before `style=`, which may not always be desirable. Nevertheless, feel free to write it up as an answer, since it does solve my question.

Comment: Then https://regex101.com/r/y7VU2i/1 would do. No need to double answers though.

Comment: To be honest, your approach is slightly different, so I would argue that it's a different answer. Both answers may have their own pros and cons. While I can't identify them, others may see a clear difference between the two, and comment on why one is way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex to match:

```
(?:\bstyle="|(?!^)\G)([^;"]+;?)\s*(?:"$)?
```

And replace it by:

```
$1\n
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tctJti/5)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. By placing `(?!^)` we ensure that `\G` is not matched at start of the line.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track. Your answer isn't 100% accurate though. In my question, I asked to include the semicolons at the end in the list. Your solution removes them. This should work in my testing: `(?:\bstyle="|(?!^)\G)(.+?;)\s*(?:[^;"]*")?`. I'm still not quite sure how this is achieved, but at least now I can do some experimenting. Thanks again.

Comment: An edit to my previous comment, for completeness: My regex there doesn't include the last item in the list if the last semicolon isn't there. This should work better: `(?:\bstyle="|(?!^)\G)([^;"]+;?)\s*(?:"$)?`

Comment: Oh yes that's a good point. I have edited as per your suggestion. Thanks!